# Nginx routing configuration

Tags: nginx

Recently, I learning the nginx.I can't understand the following the routing configuration.Can anybody explain?Thanks!

```
root /home/ubuntu/demo/web_file;
location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/demo/web_file/production;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
location /vendors {
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
location /src {
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
location /build {
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: "/venders   /src   /build  " are the static file locations. I can't understand why the file directory configuration is the same. " index  index.html index.htm;"  represent what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `root` directive is inherited from the surrounding block, if it is not specified within the `location` itself. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

The `location /` block is effectively the default location and matches any URI that does not match some other `location` block.

In your configuration, you specify the root as `/home/ubuntu/demo/web_file/production` for all URIs, except those that begin with `/vendors`, `/src`, or `build`.

---

You do not need to repeat an identical `index` statement in every location, as it is also inherited from the surrounding block, if it is not specified within the `location` itself. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

For example:

```
root /home/ubuntu/demo/web_file;
index  index.html index.htm;
location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/demo/web_file/production;
}
location /vendors {
}
location /src {
}
location /build {
}
```